# Angular2 cannot find router_providers, locationstrategy in @angular/router

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I user angular2 router and got problem with directly path.
If i write `localhost:3000/container`
Page will not be found. I knew if i include ROUTER_PROVIDERS it will be works. But i have not ROUTER_PROVIDERS and locationstrategy

Look at my screens

**root.module.ts**
[image: Module Screen]
**package.json**
[image: package.json Screen]

Comment: Can you please add at least some of your code. And what do you mean with "But i have not ROUTER_PROVIDERS and locationstrategy"?

Comment: By your question, I have perhaps found a solution. Thank you!

Comment: ok, it was not the solution for my problem, but I find your question, though quite justified!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ROUTER_DIRECTIVES and ROUTER_PROVIDERS were removed when the old @angular/router-deprecated package was removed, so you can just remove these from your import line in the module.

As for the HashLocationStrategy and LocationStrategy, these are part of the @angular/common module so you will need to do the following:

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

However, if you are wanting to enable the hash location strategy the latest recommended way to do this is to simply put the following with the routes initialisation:

```
imports: [
    ...,
    RouterModule.forRoot(rootRoutes, { useHash: true })
]
```